# How can I override FormHelper in CakePHP 3.X?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**Customised form helper per my need**

```
<?php    
namespace App\View\Helper;    
use Cake\View\Helper;

class IecFormHelper extends Helper
{  
    public $helpers = ['Form'];
    public $iecFormConfig = [        
        'templates' => [            
            'input' => '<input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}} onBlur=update_data(this.id) />',
        ]
    ];

    public function date($fieldName, array $options = [])
    {
        $options += [
            'empty' => true,
            'value' => null,
            'monthNames' => true,
            'minYear' => 1950,
            'maxYear' => date('Y') + 50,
            'orderYear' => 'desc',
        ];
        $options['hour'] = $options['minute'] = false;
        $options['meridian'] = $options['second'] = false;

        $options = $this->_initInputField($fieldName, $options);
        $options = $this->_datetimeOptions($options);

        return $this->widget('datetime', $options);
    }
}
```

I have this helper class under "src/View/Helper" which basically have template rule for  to call javascript function on blur, and also I want to change the minYear and maxYear values for all date dropdown.

My question is how and where do I use this helper so that it overrides rules in the main FormHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just load it and use your Helper instead of form helper.
If you want to overwrite Formhelper you should **extend FormHelper** in your IecFormHelper